# Converting geometry of elements of table to move it from one srid system to another

Tags: qgis, postgis, coordinate-system

I have a table containing a column geom loaded from a shape file which was defined in lambert II system (27582), but when I loaded it I specified that I want to work in lambert 93 (2154).

Unfortunately when I load it in QGIS the coordinates are always in lambert II.

Is there a function allowing me to convert these coordinates and make them pass from lambert II (27582) to lambert 93 (2154)?

I would like to work only in lambert 93.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go back and repeat the load using EPSG:27582 or use [`ST_SetSRID`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SetSRID.html) to set the correct CRS - then use the [`ST_Transform`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html) function to convert them to be in EPSG:2154 if that is what you require.

```
UPDATE table SET geom = ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(geom, 27582), 2154);
```

Though QGIS is quite capable of reprojecting on the fly for you once the correct SRID is set using just:

```
UPDATE table SET geom = ST_SetSRID(geom, 27582);
```

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly wha I want to.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is regarding PostGIS functions:

[the `ST_Transform` function](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html) is what you are looking for. Something like this should do the trick:

```
UPDATE table
SET geom = ST_Transform(geom, 2154)
```

On the other hand, if your question is refering to a QGIS operation. You can change the SRID of your layer or the whole project from its properties.